# How to evaluate strings to variables

Tags: elixir

I'm trying to get a string to evaluate to a variable. Can do that for functions but haven't been able to get variables to work.

```
old_var = "nooook"

Atom.to_string(:old) <> "_var" |> Code.eval_string
```

expected:

`nooook`

actual:

`warning: variable "old_var" does not exist and is being expanded to "old_var()", please use parentheses to remove the ambiguity or change the variable name
  nofile:1`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This won’t work for local variables because of how they are managed. [`Code.eval_string/3`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/master/Code.html#eval_string/3) accepts a binding explicitly as a second parameter, so you might:

```
Code.eval_string(Atom.to_string(:old) <> "_var", old_var: "foo")
```

*Sidenote:* `Code.eval_string/3` should not be used in client code unless you understand pretty fine why are you doing it (and even then it should be avoided.)

Answer (score 2):

You could also do some macro magic to access the variable (bypassing [Macro Hygiene](https://elixir-lang.org/getting-started/meta/macros.html#macro-hygiene).)

```rb
defmodule Variable do
  defmacro from_string(name) do
    quote do
      var!(unquote({String.to_existing_atom(name), [], Elixir}))
    end
  end
end
```

Then you can use the macro to set/get variables:

```rb
iex> old_var = "nooook"
"nooook"
iex> require Variable
iex> Variable.from_string("old_var")
"nooook"
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that way you can access variables defined in the shell. You need to bind the variables in the [eval_String](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Code.html#eval_string/3) call's second param as:

```
Code.eval_string "old_var", old_var: "noooook"
{"noooook", [old_var: "noooook"]}
```

The returned tuple will have the result of the eval as the first part, and the bindings as the second.

Answer (score 0):

You should just create a map of your strings  and values:

```
iex(17)> map = %{"old_var" => "nooook, "x" => 3, "y" => "hello"}
%{"old_var" => 10, "x" => 3, "y" => "hello"}

iex(18)> str = "old_var"                                   
"old_var"

iex(19)> map[str]
nooook

iex(20)>
```